# how to fill xfa forms using API or coding?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, pdf, xfa

I have a xfa form which I want to fill using API or coding.
currently I'm using python (Django).
is there any way to fill form using javascript or python ?
I'm new to xfa form and googled for a solution but nothing fruitful came.

Comment: Is there anything or any approach you considered and tried?

Comment: With a decent PDF library tool, you can replace the xfa data element with the new data and the form will be filled. There are any number of libraries that can do this. However, you might find it easier to convert the XFA to and XDP file so that you can use and XML library to swap out the data element without needing to alter the PDF.

Comment: I have tried to fill it as an acroform which did not work.

Comment: @joelgeraci can you recommend any pdf library tool which I can integrate with my django project as I want it to fill with the help of coding.

Comment: If you can't fill the form as an AcroForm then you have a Dynamic XFA document and modifying the "data" element in the XFA object or switching to XDP is the only way to fill it. You'll also need to view it in a Dynamic XFA capable viewer like Acrobat to see the changes. I don't use Django... Unchained or otherwise... so I can't make a recommendation.

Comment: can you tell any way to modify xfa object. I can't find any thing in google.

Comment: I have fill the form and convert it into xdp form but I cannot find values in xdp file.

Comment: I found one PDF library but it is in Java which I'm using for exporting and importing xdp files. Now I just have to make or alter xdp data using code. any suggestion ?